# Command Terminated on calling a method

Tags: c++

Upon calling this method:

```
vector<int> primeFactors(int n)
{
    printf("got this far");
    vector<int>  result;
    for(int i = 0; i < nPrimes; i++)
    {
            printf("%d %d", nPrimes, primes[i]);
            if(n % i == 0)
            {
                    printf("i = %d", i);
                    n /= i;
                    result.push_back(primes[i]);
                    i = 0;
            }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I get command terminated without it printing `got this far`

I'm calling it in the main method:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    primeFactors(n);
    return 0;
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

So the problem was that I ended up in an infite loop which is checked for by g++ causing it to terminate. The infinite loop was caused by a few errors: basically using `i` rather than `primes[i]` here is the fully correct code:

```
vector<int> primeFactors(int n)
{
    vector<int>  result;
    for(int i = 0; i < nPrimes && n > 1; i++)
    {
            if(n % primes[i] == 0)
            {
                    n /= primes[i];
                    result.push_back(primes[i]);
                    i = -1;
            }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Check return value of scanf, always. Otherwise, things will get "funny" (and not in a good way) when there is invalid input.

Comment: that was the first thing that I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is a error in your code:

During calling this function:

```
vector<int> primeFactors(int n)
{
    printf("got this far");
    vector<int>  result;
    for(int i = 0; i < nPrimes; i++)
    {
            printf("%d %d", nPrimes, primes[i]);
            if(n % i == 0)
            {
                    printf("i = %d", i);
                    n /= i;
```

Here your `i` is 0 thus it will cause a crash caused by dividing by zero. The reason you don't have a output of your `printf` because the `stdout` buffer was not flushed. Use `flush()` after `printf()` call to flush the buffers or insert a new line character in your printable string:

```
printf("got this far\n");
```

P.S. I/O operations are buffered. They are flushed some time by OS or some time after explicit ask (sync/fsync/flush).

Comment: that will be it thanks but why would it not even print 'got this far' ?

Comment: `Cjen1` your program is terminated because you have `divide by zero` error. Also, you will not see any buffered data because it is in the buffer, not in actual file (stdout). You must flush it to be able to see the data. Also what is `nPrimes`, `primes`? Just tried, everything works as expected.

Comment: nPrimes and primes are just a list of all possible prime factors for my input size, btw got it fixed, there were a few errors, but your flushing of the buffers helped. The problem was that it ended up in an infinite loop. I was using input 4 for testing once I fixed the devide by z error (basically all comparisons should have been `primes[i]` rather than `i` hence it ran into an infinite loop (2 wasn't getting checked due to i++ running after the end of the loop) causing the command to terminate.